# GWT add div into panel

Tags: java, gwt, html

I have a div into my html project gwt `<div id="myproject"></div>` how can add this into a specific vertical panel?

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
VerticalPanel verticalPanel = new VerticalPanel();

verticalPanel.add(RootPanel.get("myproject"));

RootPanel.get().add(verticalPanel);
```

Comment: not run , not show the panel , it show on a root panel when i start but not appears in a panel

Comment: You have to add your panel into RootPanel. It works for me.

Comment: ok i have in my div style="display:none how can do to change this parameter when i add to my panel

Comment: place this "DOM.getElementById("myproject").setAttribute("style","");" after "RootPanel.get().add(verticalPanel);"

Comment: it give me javascript exception

Comment: in my code i need to create and destroy many time this object it show one time but it give me many error when i tr to recreate

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [HtmlPanel](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/HTMLPanel.html)

```
panel.add(new HtmlPanel("<div id=\"myproject\"></div>"));
```